# How to properly resize a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, fontsize

Apparently text is resized in [one way](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/LaTeXChangingTheFont) and math in [other way](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Changing_font_size). However, the commands to resize math do not work well on a matrix; it appears barely smaller and unexpectedly shifted down. The commands to resize text also "work well" to resize a matrix except that it give a warning that you are doing it wrong.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode on input line 16.
```

So, what is a proper way to resize a matrix that actually works?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 Properly resize variable: $x$ $\scriptscriptstyle{x}$

 Properly resize matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ $\scriptscriptstyle{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}}$

 Improperly resize matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ $\scriptsize{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Size changing commands such as `\small` or `\scriptsize` are invalid
   in math mode.
2. `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` are not commands with an argument; writing `$\scriptstyle<formula>$` or `$\scriptstyle{<formula>}$` has exactly the same result.
3. Neither `$\scriptsize\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}$` nor `$\scriptstyle\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}$` work, as you experimented
4. If you need small matrices there's the `smallmatrix` environment (with **amsmath** that you're already loading).
5. Another way (not that I recommend it) is to say `\mbox{\scriptsize$\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}$}` inside a math formula.

Comment: 4. But they didn't include the corresponding `smallbmatrix`??

Comment: I guess not:
http://www.utexas.edu/ogs/etd/LaTeX/Mathematics+AMS/amsmdoc.pdf

Comment: `\left[\begin{smallmatrix}...\end{smallmatrix}\right]`